# WordPress rewrite URL returning 404 Not Found

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect this url:

**myurl.com/track/124**

to this one:

**myurl.com/wp-content/themes/themefolder/track.php?id=124**

The parameter value **124** can be anything.  I have modified the .htaccess file on the root of the server so now it has this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^track/?$ wp-content/themes/themefolder/track.php?id=$1 [QSA,R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However when I go to myurl.com/track/124 I 404 Not Found returned.  Can anyone spot the problem and help me fix this?

- Another question: Is there a way to make sure the URL does not show **wp-content/themes/themefolder/track.php?id=124** and keeps is **track/124**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change

```
RewriteRule ^track/?$ wp-content/themes/themefolder/track.php?id=$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^track/(\d+) wp-content/themes/themefolder/track.php?id=$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

Comment: Hey this works. Thanks - Could you tell me why if I take it out of the wordpress block (I'm worried an update would overwrite it) it fails again?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Wordpress' built in function [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

```
add_filter('init','my_rewrite_rules');
function my_rewrite_rules(){
     add_rewrite_rule('^track/([^/]*)/?','wp-content/themes/themefolder/track.php?id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

You will then need to visit your permalinks page in settings (Dashboard->Settings->Permalinks->Save Changes) in order for the added rule to take effect.

Comment: That doesn't work. When I var_dump($_GET['id']) I get: string(11) "$matches[1]" - it doesnt appear to be passing the integer value across.

Comment: don't use $_GET, use get_query_var('id')